# Getting first 3 items from multi-dim array

Tags: php

I'm needing to loop over an array and echo out the first 3 elements, however my issue is the first 3 wont always be within the first parent element. In my example below I need to get the first 3 of the inner element 'Items'

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'Items' => array(
            0 => "dave",
            1 => "steve"
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'Items' => array(
            0 => "megan"
         )
    )
)
```

In that example the expected result would echo
    Dave
    Steve
    Megan

Much appreciated! :)

Comment: What's wrong with a nested foreach loop and a counter to get the first three?

Comment: That's what I've got currently, was hoping to use a nice iterator but I guess this will do - just a small script for a client. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This will print out the correct output:

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'Items' => array(
            0 => "dave",
            1 => "steve"
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'Items' => array(
            0 => "megan"
        )
    )
);

$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));

for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $it->next();

    $value = $it->current();
    echo $value, " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For small arrays, you could use `array_walk_recursive`:

```
$output = array();

array_walk_recursive($array, function ($value, $key, $elements) {
    if (count($elements) < 3) {
        $elements[] = $value;
    }
}, $output);
```

However, for a large `$array`, this would be unnecessarily slow, since it loops over the entire array just to get the first 3 elements. In that case, you could implement the walk yourself:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
$output = array();

while (count($output) < 3 && $iterator->valid()) {
    $iterator->next();
    $output[] = $iterator->current();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my code:

```
    <?php
    $arr = array( 0 => array('Items' => array(0 => "dave",1 => "steve")),1 => array('Items' => array(0 => "megan")));
    $out = '';
    $c = 0;
    foreach($arr as $all_items) {
        foreach($all_items['Items'] as $ne_items) {
            $out .= $ne_items.' ';
            $c++;
           if($c == 3) {
                break;
           }
        }
       if($c == 3) {
            break;
        }
    }

    echo $out;
```